# Why error here with cucumber runner mutiple tags

Tags: cucumber, automation-testing

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zfYl9.png)

Error is "Type mismatch: cannot convert from String[] to String".

But this is the guide in cucumber webpage:

```
package com.example;

import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(tags = {"@foo", "not @bar"})
public class RunCucumberTest {
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cucumber used to have some really complex semantics for combining tags. You could either write:

```
tags = { "@gherkin", "@pickle", "@zuchini" }
```

Or:

```
tags = { "@gherkin, @pickle, @zuchini" }
```

And even:

```
tags = { "@gherkin", "@pickle, @zuchini" }
```

And they'd all mean different things. This made it quite difficult to explain and understand what scenarios would be selected.

By using a single tag expression string that can be done more clearly. So you drop the curly braces and write:

```
tags = "(@gherkin or @pickle) and not @zuchini"
```