# Unable to add multiple tags in test runner file

Tags: selenium, junit, cucumber, serenity-bdd, cucumber-junit

I am trying to execute test cases based on tags. I can able to execute a test case if i add one tag but when i try to add multiple tags (`tags = {"@regression or "@smoke"}`) I'm getting a syntax error [image]

Even i tried to use `tags = "@smoke or @regression"` this has end up with there are no test for given tag. please let me know the right syntax to handle multiple tags in the runner file

Runner file:

```
package TestRunner;

import Utility.Constants;
import com.Base.PageBase;
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;
import net.serenitybdd.cucumber.CucumberWithSerenity;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

@RunWith(CucumberWithSerenity.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        //plugin = {"pretty"},
        tags = {"@regression" or "@smoke"},
        //dryRun = true,
        features = {"TestSuites/s   rc/test/java/features/Account"},
        glue = {"StepDefinitions"})
public class AccountsTestRunner extends PageBase {
    @BeforeClass
    public static void createTestRunnerSuite() throws IOException {
        Utility.ExcelReader excelReader = new Utility.ExcelReader();
        List<Integer> testIds = excelReader.suiteReader(Constants.ACCOUNTS_SHEET_NAME);
        System.out.println(testIds);
//         TestBase.createSuite("Account - Regression-QC High Priority Automation Sprint 11-12", testIds, Constants.ACCT_SUITE_ID);
    }
}
```

build.gradle:

```
defaultTasks 'clean', 'test', 'aggregate'

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'net.serenity-bdd.aggregator'

group 'org.automationserenity'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

buildscript {
    project.ext {
        serenityVersion = '2.3.12'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath('net.serenity-bdd:serenity-gradle-plugin:' + serenityVersion)

    }

}


sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

ext {
    slf4jVersion = '1.7.7'
    serenityCoreVersion = '3.0.5'
    junitVersion = '4.11'
    assertJVersion = '3.21.0'
    logbackVersion = '1.2.3'
    serenityCucumberVersion = '3.0.5'
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.7.0'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter-api
    testImplementation group: 'org.junit.jupiter', name: 'junit-jupiter-api', version: '5.7.0'
    //implementation group: 'io.cucumber', name: 'cucumber-java', version: '6.11.0'
    implementation group: 'net.serenity-bdd', name: 'serenity-cucumber6', version: '2.3.2'

    testImplementation "net.serenity-bdd:serenity-core:${serenityCoreVersion}",
            "net.serenity-bdd:serenity-junit:${serenityCoreVersion}",
            "net.serenity-bdd:serenity-screenplay:${serenityCoreVersion}",
              "net.serenity-bdd:serenity-cucumber:${serenityCucumberVersion}",
            //"junit:junit:${junitVersion}",
            "org.assertj:assertj-core:${assertJVersion}"
    implementation group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpclient', version: '4.5.13'
    implementation group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpcore', version: '4.4.14'
    implementation group: 'org.json', name: 'json', version: '20210307'
    implementation group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-databind', version: '2.12.3'
    implementation 'com.github.javafaker:javafaker:1.0.2'
    implementation group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi', version: '5.0.0'
    testImplementation group: 'com.jayway.restassured', name: 'rest-assured', version: '2.9.0'
    testImplementation group: 'io.rest-assured', name: 'rest-assured', version: '3.2.0'
    implementation group: 'io.github.bonigarcia', name: 'webdrivermanager', version: '3.0.0'
    implementation group: 'org.jboss.aerogear', name: 'aerogear-otp-java', version: '1.0.0'
//        implementation group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-java', version: '4.0.0-beta-4'
    implementation group: 'commons-configuration', name: 'commons-configuration', version: '1.10'
    implementation group: 'net.serenity-bdd', name: 'serenity-reports', version: '2.4.51'
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml
    implementation group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi-ooxml', version: '5.0.0'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.json-simple/json-simple
    implementation group: 'com.googlecode.json-simple', name: 'json-simple', version: '1.1'
    implementation group: 'net.serenity-bdd', name: 'serenity-zalenium', version: '2.3.13'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.appium/java-client
    implementation group: 'com.applitools', name: 'eyes-selenium-java3', version: '3.208.2'
    implementation group: 'com.jayway.jsonpath', name: 'json-path', version: '2.6.0'

}
test {
    testLogging.showStandardStreams = true
    systemProperties System.getProperties()
}


tasks.withType(Test) {
    maxParallelForks = Runtime.runtime.availableProcessors()

    filter {

        includeTestsMatching "*AccountsTestRunner"

    }

}

gradle.startParameter.continueOnFailure = true
test.finalizedBy(aggregate, reports)



dependencies {
    implementation 'org.mongodb:mongodb-driver:3.12.10'
    implementation group: 'org.mongodb', name: 'mongo-java-driver', version: '3.12.8'
    implementation 'org.mongodb:mongodb-driver-sync:4.5.0'
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.ozlerhakan/poiji
    implementation group: 'com.github.ozlerhakan', name: 'poiji', version: '3.1.1'
}
```

Comment: https://testingneeds.wordpress.com/tag/cucumberoptions/
please check section-  'Running cucumber tests based on Tags' and try the mentioned combinations as you need.

Comment: I followed same syntax but got error after enclosing tags with {} (`Example: tags = {"@tag1","@tag2"}`)

Comment: This answer helped me [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68673769/why-error-here-with-cucumber-runner-mutiple-tags)

Comment: yes @M.P.Korstanje

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this should compile and work at least:

> tags = "@TEST1 or @TEST2"

Comment: no this did not work for me and I got no test found for the given filter. but i tried `tags = "(@TEST1 or @TEST2)"` answered in the [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68673769/why-error-here-with-cucumber-runner-mutiple-tags) it worked well