# How to run multiple tags in CucumberOptions

Tags: java, selenium, junit, cucumber, automation-testing

I've two different feature files 1 has @Feature1 and 2 has @Feature2
I want to run only these two features with tags
My TestRunner code this gives sytnax error on tags

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        features = "src/main/resources/features",
        glue = "stepDefinition",
        tags = {"@Feature1", "@Feature2"}
)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why error here with cucumber runner mutiple tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68673769/why-error-here-with-cucumber-runner-mutiple-tags)

Comment: @M.P.Korstanje No adding curly braces is giving me an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To execute multiple tag one after another you need to use or . See example below

```
tags={“@tag1 or @tag2”}
```

Comment: Gives me this error: "java: annotation value not of an allowable type"

Comment: Just remove the curl braces and try as ur using junit runner

Comment: tags=“@tag1 or @tag2”